# Why cant module.export make an array available for a js file but export does?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module.exports

A newbie here trying to understand how module.export vs export works.

When I use export { arr } and import { arr } from '../js/export.js';  everything works just fine. So that I could implement and use html to print the array onto the browser.

But using module.export does not work in the same way and I could not find any explanation that explains in a way that a node.js beginner can understand. Just to show exactly what I am trying to implement I will post the code I used for module.export , js and html to make it clear whats happening.

to recap I used export{} and import{} and everything works perfectly without any problems. That I understood perfectly but the problem will arise later when implementing more complex code and at that point I personally would prefer to use module.exports because it makes writing complex stuff much easier at least for my level of understanding.  But I cant even understand how to get the array and print it. I used console.log() to test if the array can be printed from the imnporting file and it actually printed the array to the console with no problems. Thta means the problem lays with the browser and js file importing the file and thats where I am stuck as to how exactly to get the browser to print the array

```
//js model


module.exports = function somefunction() {
  
    this.arrayss = function () {
       
        var arr = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
        
        return arr;
    };

};
```

```
// js file to import model

var fetch = require('../c');
var c = new fetch();
var arr = c.arrayss

function buildProducts(parent, array) {
    var html = "";

    array.forEach(function (i) {
        //Set Our Itemp template
        let itemTemplate = `
  <li>

     <div>item:  ${i}</div>

  </li>`;
        //update the html 
        html += itemTemplate
    });
    //Update the parent once
    parent.innerHTML += html;
}

buildProducts(document.getElementById("jj"), arr);
```

```
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
   
    <div id="jj"></div>
   
    <script type="module" src="/js/importfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `import` and `export` are a different module mechanism than `require()` and `module.exports`. They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different module formats for JavaScript, but the two most common ones in 2023 are CommonJS modules and ECMAScript modules.

Node.js has native support for both and recognises which module format is being used based on the `type` specified in *package.json* and the file extension.

Web browsers (where you are running your code) **only** support ECMAScript modules natively.

`import` and `export` are the syntax used by ECMAScript modules.

`require()` and `module.exports` are used by CommonJS (which aren't natively supported by browsers).

Comment: Okay so in essence you are saying that what I attempted with my code above will not work(array printed to browser). But then how does one get access to the array for use else where? I mean maybe I can copy the target array to another array and print that , but I am unsure. As you can see people down voted my post but to bring solutions or explanations , they are not capable. Infact there are none on the whole web at least the sites I clicked. At least you doing something so thanks. I mean how can I now get the array and use it?

Comment: Err. You make it an ECMAScript module using ECMAScript syntax.